# Basic D3.js: how to bind data with other attributes to elements?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have an array that looks like this, where each item is an airport, defined by its name and flight frequency:

```
var mydata = [
    {'name' : 'LHR', 'flights' : [ { x : 0, y : 1520 }, { x : 1, y : 1990 } ] },
    {'name' : 'SFO', 'flights' : [ { x : 0, y : 2090 }, { x : 1, y : 2170 } ] }
];
```

I want to draw a line with D3.js for each entry in the array. I'd like to bind the `flights` data to the line, and I'd like to give the line a classname corresponding to `name`, so that I end up with paths looking like this:

```
<path class="LHR" d="...flights data..."></path>
<path class="SFO" d="...flights data..."></path>
```

How can I bind the data and give the line a classname at the same time? Can I do something like this?

```
svg.selectall("path.line")
   .data(mydata, function(d) { return d.flights})
   .enter()
   .append("path")
   .attr("class", "line")
   .attr("class", function(d) { return d.name})
   .attr("d", line);
```

I'm not sure that this call to `data()` will work properly. Or maybe it will? I can restructure my data if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out - the answer is to make the function call in the `attr` line, not in the `data` line:

```
svg.selectAll("path.line")
  .data(mydata)
  .enter()
  .append("path")
  .attr("class", function(d) { return 'line ' + d.name; })
  .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.flights); });​
```